# Getting the value of an input element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, input

I would like to get the value of a input using a the a chain class as the identifier in jquery. is this possible?

I have the following code

```
<input class="donate-block__value monthly" type="text" id="donation-amount" name="DonationAmount" value="200" />
```

and i have tried the following which has resulted in undefined

```
var monthlyDonation = $('.donate-block__value .monthly').val();
var monthlyDonation = $('donate-block__value monthly').val();

console.log(monthlyDonation);
```

I need to target the class Can this be done please?

Answer (score 5):

Don't add space between your classes or jquery will start to search within the first class looking for a child element. use it like this:

```
var monthlyDonation = $('.donate-block__value.monthly').val();
```

Comment: Thats it :)! I cant believe i missed that. Its been a long day. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can also target just the `input` element in case you have multiple elements with that class defined:

`$('input.donate-block__value.monthly').val();`

Answer (score 0):

Your selector `.donate-block__value .monthly` is referring to an element within an element.  Try just `.donate-block__value` or `.monthly`